# Ajax a submitted form FILE to another PHP PARSER

Tags: php, ajax, forms, post, jscript

I cannot get the syntax correct and Basically Parse the file props/full info to the Parser (After the parent page submitted the form ) -- if you understand what i mean. Il post the basic gist of the code . If anybody can see what is should be Posting or another way to Ajax the file , would be greatly appreciated.

This is the form in the uploads page (html)

```
<input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" accept="image/*" required />
```

From there it posts to the Profile page, Which displays the image and runs a few handlers ect. But iv involved somebody elses code for a progress bar and iv got a little stuck at this part. Forwarding the correct way to the Parser..
The script below parses but in an errornous mannor. I get error Undefined variable FILE1

In profile page i tried another hidden form

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' autocomplete='on'>
<input type='file' id='file1' style='display:none;' name='file1'>unsure about the following--> VALUE="<?PHP $_FILES['file1'] ?>">
</form>
```

But i cannot get this script to post the full props . it only sends the name details, as i manage to get a filename readback and filesize. But nothing more... I guess im posting the form and script all wrong.

```
  <script>
            /* Script written by Adam Khoury @ DevelopPHP.com */
            /* Video Tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EraNFJiY0Eg */
            function _(el){
                return document.getElementById(el);

            }
            $(document).ready(function uploadFile(){
                var file = _("file1").files[0];
                // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
                var formdata = new FormData();
                formdata.append("file1", file);
                var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
                ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
                ajax.send(formdata);
            });
            function progressHandler(event){
                _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
                var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
                _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
                _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
            }
            function completeHandler(event){
                _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
                _("progressBar").value = 100;
            }
            function errorHandler(event){
                _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
            }
            function abortHandler(event){
                _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
            }
            </script>
```

P.s Probly a few errors in the html, but its just shorthand.. The script is copy pasted though.

Comment: This post is all over the place. Not even sure what you're asking. Please edit and correct spelling and grammar mistakes. This looks more like an issue with jQuery/JavaScript than it does with PHP.

Comment: Would review more here: http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/File-Upload-Progress-Bar-Meter-Tutorial-Ajax-PHP

Comment: But its the same bloody script lol

Comment: Try checking for console errors.